# Тестирование map

Tags: golang

Каким образом тестировать `map` в golang? У меня есть функция  *argmin* из ассоциотивного массива `map`. Сигнатура этой функции выглядит так:

```
func ArgminMap(m map[int]int) (int, error)
```

**Проблема**. `map` в golang реализован таким образом, что не предоставляет никакой гарантии о порядке обхода элементов. Если я инициализирую `map` таким образом:

```
m := map[int]int{}
for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
    m[i] = i
}
```

то нет никакой гарантии, что при двух запусках программы, `m` будет инициализирован одинаково. Т.е. листинг:

```
for k, v := range m {
    fmt.Println(k, v)
}
```

для каждого нового запуска может отличаться от каждого предыдущего:

```
 Запуск 1:
    0 0
    1 1
    3 3
    5 5
    6 6
    8 8
    9 9
    2 2
    4 4
    7 7


 Запуск 2:
    1 1
    2 2
    3 3
    4 4
    5 5
    6 6
    7 7
    8 8
    9 9
    0 0
```

Возникает вопрос, как сравнивать ответы алгоритма, если в ответ для функции `argmin` не единственный?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Делать то же, что делают пакеты `encoding/json` и, [с Go 1.12](https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.12#fmt), `fmt`: брать ключи, сортировать, и проходиться в сортированном порядке. Мапы в го не дают никаких гарантий по порядку, так же как `select` не даёт гарантий по порядку получения сигналов, так что если вам нужны воспроизводимые результаты, то  это ваша работа сделать их таковыми.

Comment: Другим вариантом является следующий. Учитывать все возможные ответы. Если функция `argmin` выдаёт один из них, то считать, что тест прошёл

Comment: @hedgehogues Зависит от ситуации. Без контекста сказать сложно. Вы даже можете включать/выключать сортировку через флаг в коде.